# What is the better way to assign and call methods in Angular component?

Tags: angular

What do I mean? There is some method and some property of component class:

```
private someData: SomeData = {x: 1, y: 1};

private doSomething(someData: SomeData): void { do something with someData }
or 
private doSomething(): void { do something with this.someData }
```

I have implementation of OnInit and the question is what is the better way from these to call?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.doSomething(this.someData);
  or
  this.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: What makes the difference in sending information as arguments?

Comment: @PandiyanCool It makes your code more testable.

Comment: @Roy but he didn't mentioned anything about testing

Comment: I didn't mention anything about testing but similar arguments are exactly that I need.

Comment: Private members are not testable, you test them through the public members.

Comment: As for the question, I tend to use the 2nd option by default and fall back to the 1st one in cases when there are multiple sources of `someData`, e.g. an event and a local field.